# Order of quotienting by subspaces to form a quotient space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Context/Background: Often it is asked in some exams - what is the space obtained by collapsing meridional and longitudinal circle of a Mobius strip or similar type of things. When I look at the solutions available, they usually start with a rectangle, then do identifications in an order that is different than that done to obtain Mobius strip from a rectangle. So I am thinking about how to justify this change in the order of identifications.

Suppose that $X$ is a topological space, and that $A_1,...,A_n$ are its subspaces.

Given a permutation $\sigma\in S_n$ and a space $X$, define $X_\sigma^1:=X/A_{\sigma 1}$. Inductively define $X_\sigma^n:=X_\sigma^{n-1}/A_{\sigma (n-1)}$.

Now, suppose that $\rho\in S_n$ is such that $\rho\ne \sigma$, 1) is it true then that $X_\sigma^{n+1}=X_\rho^{n+1}$ homeomorphically? 2) Is it true that $X_\sigma ^{n+1}= X/A$, where $A=\cup_{i=1}^n A_i$?

How does one prove these statements if they are correct?

Let's use induction. The statement is true for $n=1$. Suppose it is true for all $n\lt k, k>1$. So we want to now show that it holds for $n=k$. This would prove it by induction for all $n\in \mathbb N$.

We have, $X^{k+1}_\sigma=X_\sigma^k/A_{\sigma (k)}= X_\rho^k/A_{\color{red}\sigma (k)}$, where the second equality is by induction hypothesis. How do I get $\rho$ in place of red colored $\sigma$ to prove the result, if it is true?

Comment: Point 2 is not true in general. Consider $X=\{1,2\}$ with $A_1=\{1\}$ and $A_2=\{2\}$. Note that quotients step by step don't change anything, we end up with $X$ every time. But $X/(A_1\cup A_2)$ is a singleton.

Comment: Do you assume that the $A_i$ are pairwise disjoint?

Comment: @PaulFrost No, they don't need to be pairwise disjoint.

Comment: @PaulFrost: Ah, it won't make sense if the A_i are not disjoint. So we may suppose them to be pairwise disjoint.

Comment: @freakish: I see. Thanks. But why doesn't step by step quotienting doesn't change anything?

Comment: @Koro because both $A_1$ and $A_2$ are singletons. Given any space $X$ and any point $x\in X$ the space $X/\{x\}$ is homeomorphic to $X$. Simply because the quotient map $\pi:X\to X/\{x\}$ is bijective. And bijective quotient maps are homeomorphisms.

Comment: @freakish: Ok. I thought you were referring to (1) in the post. But you were referring to the example that you gave.

Answer (score 1):

Point 2) is based on a misconception, as has been pointed out in the comments. Indeed, if the $A_1,\,\dotsc,A_n$ are pairwise disjoint, the resulting space is clearly (and independently of the permutation $\sigma$) up to homeomorphism the space obtained from $X$  by collapsing *each* $A_i,\,i=1,\dotsc,n$ *individually* to a single point. For another example, consider also the case $n=2$ and suppose $A_1$ and $A_2$ intersect. This hypothesis is equivalent to the image of $A_2$ in $X/A_1$ containing the point $A_1/A_1$, so the result of collapsing this image in $X/A_1$ yields up to homeomorphism the space $X/(A_1\cup A_2)$ indeed. As you can see, the ways in which the $A_i$ do or do not intersect is significant. The general case will be a combination of the two phenomena just observed.

In general, let $\sim$ be the equivalence relation on $I=\{1,\dotsc,n\}$ generated by $i\sim j$ if $A_i\cap A_j\neq\emptyset$. Then, for each $[i]\in I/\sim$, let $B_{[i]}=\bigcup_{j\in[i]}A_j$ (note the $B_{[i]}$ are pairwise disjoint!). Now, I claim that the quotient map $X\rightarrow X_{\sigma}^{n+1}$ describes $X_{\sigma}^{n+1}$ up to homeomorphism as the result of collapsing *each* $B_{[i]},\,[i]\in I/\sim$ *individually* to a single point. This description is easily seen to be invariant under permuting the $A_1,\dotsc,A_n$ (which results in a permutation of the $B_{[i]},\,[i]\in I/\sim$), so as a corollary we obtain that 1) is true. Thus, assume $\sigma=id$ WLOG forthcoming.

Let's prove the claim by induction. The base case $n=1$ is trivial. Now, assume it is has been proven for some $n$ and we are given $A_1,\dotsc,A_{n+1}\subseteq X$. From the induction hypothesis, we know that $X\rightarrow X_{id}^{n+1}$ describes $X_{id}^{n+1}$ up to homeomorphism as the result of collapsing each $B_{[i]},\,[i]\in I/\sim$ individually to a point, where these sets are as before. Let's call this space $Y$. Now, $X_{id}^{n+2}$ is obtained by collapsing the image of $A_{n+1}$ in $X_{id}^{n+1}$ to a point. Thanks to the induction hypothesis, we may instead collapse the image of $A_{n+1}$ in $Y$ to a point. Let $I^{\prime}=\{1,\dotsc,n+1\}$ and $\sim^{\prime}$ be the corresponding equivalence relation on $I^{\prime}$. If $[i_1],\dotsc,[i_k]\in I/\sim$ are precisely the equivalence classes such that the points $B_{[i_1]}/\sim,\dotsc,B_{[i_k]}/\sim$ are contained in the image of $A_{n+1}$ in $Y$, then $I^{\prime}/\sim$ consists  precisely of the equivalence classes of $I/\sim$ that are not $[i_1],\dotsc,[i_k]$ and one equivalence classes that is the union of $[i_1],\dotsc,[i_k]$ and $\{n+1\}$ (note that this also works if $k=0$). Thus, the space obtained from $Y$ by collapsing the image of $A_{n+1}$ to a point is up to homeomorphism the same as the space obtained from $X$ by collapsing each $B_{[i^{\prime}]},\,[i^{\prime}]\in I^{\prime}/\sim^{\prime}$ individually to point, as desired.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I am still going through it and trying to understand it.